# Interface and extending

Tags: java, interface, extends

Having trouble with how to use the following code or if even possible.
I am new to this. 
I have the following:

**variables.java**

```
public interface variables extends library{
     public int func1(String a, String b);
     public int func2(String a, String b); 
}
```

**CallVariables.java**

```
public CallVariables extends variables{
    String hi = "Hi";
    String by = "Bye";
    //Then here somehow call my variables.java and be able to use it...
}
```

**main.java**

```
// Now, here I want to be able to actually call the first or either the second .java class.
// Is this possible? If yes, then how?
```

I would like to know if this is even possible and please kindly include and example if can.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are declared by specifying a keyword “interface”. E.g.:

```
interface MyInterface
{
   /* All the methods are public abstract by default
    * As you see they have no body
    */
   public void method1();
   public void method2();
}
```

**Example of an Interface in Java**

This is how a class implements an interface. It has to provide the body of all the methods that are declared in interface or with other words you can say that class has to implement all the methods of interface.

A class implements interface but an interface extends another interface.

```
interface MyInterface
{
   /* compiler will treat them as: 
    * public abstract void method1();
    * public abstract void method2();
    */
   public void method1();
   public void method2();
}
class Demo implements MyInterface
{
   /* This class must have to implement both the abstract methods
    * else you will get compilation error
    */
   public void method1()
   {
    System.out.println("implementation of method1");
   }
   public void method2()
   {
    System.out.println("implementation of method2");
   }
   public static void main(String arg[])
   {
    MyInterface obj = new Demo();
    obj.method1();
   }
}
```

**Output:**

`implementation of method1`

I hope this has created a bit more clarity about how a class works with an interface.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you! Helps me!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the naming convention for interface and class.
class can implements interafce, interface can extends another interface and class can extends one class.
This may help you:

```
interface Library{}
//First variables.java:
     interface Variables extends Library{
         public int func1(String a, String b);
         public int func2(String a, String b); 
    }

//Second call Variables.java
     class CallVariables implements Variables{
         String hi = "Hi";
         String by = "Bye";
         //Then here somehow call my variables.java and be able to use it...
        @Override
        public int func1(String a, String b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("func1 says :"+hi);
            return 1;
        }
        @Override
        public int func2(String a, String b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("func2 says :"+by);
            return 2;
        }
     }
//Third main.java
     //Now, here I want to be able to actually call the first or either the second .java class. 
    // Is this possible? If yes, then how? 
     public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Variables variables = new CallVariables();
            variables.func1("a", "b");
            variables.func2("c", "d");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped you. please  consider up vote if it helped you or accept as answer if it is solution.